# Set dynamic _DEFAULT_PI_VARS

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I must set `plugin.tt_news._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.tt_news` to show the latest news by default. So I get the uid of the latest news via `CONTENT`.

```
temp.newsUid = CONTENT
temp.newsUid {
    table = tt_news
    select {
        pidInList = 12345
        orderBy = datetime DESC
        join = tt_news_cat_mm ON tt_news_cat_mm.uid_local = tt_news.uid
        where = tt_news_cat_mm.uid_foreign = 4711 AND tt_news.deleted = 0 AND tt_news.hidden = 0
        max = 1
    }

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = uid
    }
}

plugin.tt_news._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.tt_news = temp.newsUid
```

will not work. But how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
plugin.tt_news._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.tt_news.stdWrap.cObject < temp.newsUid
```

Comment: if this is the solution, please mark your answer as solution! thanks

Comment: I can’t accept my own answer immediately. For now I have to wait 8 hours for accepting my own answer. But yes, this seems to be the solution for my question.